# Local IIS can't access from mobile

Tags: angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework, iis-7.5, visual-studio-cordova

I have local IIS on my local PC.I setup a service to upload files, does some operations and return value. The problem is I can NOT access this URL from mobile browser. **Other PC's in the same network can access this service URL from browser**. How can I fix this?

http://10.126.111.99/wcf/OCRService.svc

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

edit 1: phone is also in the same network.

Comment: can you ping from phone to server?

Comment: Hi @PeteHouston, now I am at home and changed the wi-fi and bingo. It is reachable. But how can I make it work at the office?

Comment: then ask your network administrator. I also need to ask my network admin at work, same situation as yours.

Comment: I talked to the admin, he said it is NOT allowed to access from mobile to this IP from my location. So mobile access is forbidden.

Comment: it is not a technical problem then; it is your company network policy.

Comment: yes @PeteHouston exactly.

Comment: If your network admin is preventing access, there is little you can do.  However, one possibility if you have a guest network is to join your phone and a laptop to that and see if you can access.  Reading your mail it sounds like you're on the same broader network but different network segments that can't communicate.

Comment: @ChuckLantz thank you , I will try it.